# Get fatal error when install psycopg2

Tags: virtualenv, python-3.3, psycopg2

I created a virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper using Python 3.

```
mkvirtualenv foo -p /usr/bin/python3
```

I tried to do a `pip` install of `psycopg2` and got the following error:

```
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

I have the most recent version of `python-dev`.  I can successfully install `psycopg2` with a virtualenv using Python 2.

What is the trick to getting it install in a virtualenv using Python 3?

Comment: Did you try this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074355 ?, it says that with python3 you need python3-dev or python3.2-dev instead of python-dev in order to install Python.h for python3

Comment: That was indeed the fix!  If you want to put that as an answer I'll get you the bounty.  Thanks.

Comment: I post the comment as an answer. Thanks :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you try [the solution found here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074355)?

It might be that with your `python3` environment you need `python3-dev` or `python3.2-dev` instead of `python-dev` in order to install `Python.h` for python3.

Comment: Just installed python 3.4 and assumed python3-dev would suffice. Nope. Had to do python3.4-dev. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you using python3.4 try to install `python34-devel` by running this command

```
 sudo yum install python34-devel
```